# How to use combobox with foreign datasource while editing row in a grid?

Tags: gridview, kendo-ui

ASP.Net MVC 3, Kendo UI Web, Kendo grid control.

My main datasource uses foreign datasource via foreign key binding:

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.ForeignKey(p => p.FK_ID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["things"], "ID", "NAME");
    ...
```

In view mode, binding works as expected, I see `NAME` property bound by "FK_ID - ID" relation.

However when I enter edit mode strange things happen:

- in inline mode -- the column is disabled (i.e. there is no editor for this field of any kind)
- in popup mode -- there is an editbox editor, not combobox, so I have to type it manually despite the fact of binding

On the Kendo website the demo shows, that in case of foreign keys in edit mode, combobox is shown and the choice is limited to the foreign datasource (pretty common sense).

So what should I do additionally to show combobox and choose only from the values shown there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please check whether you have the foreign key editor which is required? It should be under the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder and its name is **GridForeignKey.cshtml** (or .aspx if using ASPX view engine)

If it is not there you can add it by hand using the info from above. The content of the editor is:

```
@( Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""))
    .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I ask you how the binding is done? I mean I have grid `A`, and the GridForeignKey is picked because it is picked for every grid with foreign keys, or because I have to do some extra setup somewhere?

Comment: Not sure I understand you. The GridForeignKey editor is used for each Grid and each column that is defined as a ForeignKey column. Basically that editor template is automatically added to your project if you create a project with the Kendo VisualStudio extension.

http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-08-15/rocking_kendo_ui_in_visual_studio_2012_and_windows_8.aspx

Comment: I rephrase. You add this editor template once, and it will be used for all grids with foreign keys, correct?

Comment: Sure thing, I was just waiting for confirmation, so I have full answer :-). Thank you!